# What kind of projects can you show in your resume as an aspiring systems administrator(linux/windows)?

Tags: software, it

I am an aspiring linux/windows(mainly linux as I love it) system administrator and currently a helpdesk. I also like devops. What projects can I show? I've written scripts, but they're max like 100 lines. So, I don't think it's worth showing. I've wrote node.js projects but I don't want to include them on my resume which might fool the employer thinking I want a javascript backend job.

What can I do? My resume is pretty empty that's why.

I've been working as an tier 2 helpdesk since 1 year and  have computer engineering degree with first division rank.

Comment: What *is* on your resume? Do you have a solid education you can list? Normally, "projects" are seen as a last ditch replacement for education or work experience. What does "aspiring" mean in your case?

Comment: @nvoigt, I guess the OP is probably a college student, and has no work experience in the industry.

Comment: No I'm employed as tier 2 helpdesk already.

Comment: I've computer engineering degree but it's only 1 line on resume and it feels empty. I've 1 YOE of experience but still that is only 8-9 lines.

Comment: "computer engineering degree but it's only 1 line on resume" This is only because you are choosing to make it one line on your resumé, you have the power to expand it into something more meaningful. But if you want to ask about that, please do it as a separate question.

Comment: If your resume is empty, you have 2 choices: (1) Fill it with some honest experiences, or (2) leave it empty. Which one should you prefer ? You are only being honest when you list your linux scripting and nodeJS on your resume. So, you should list them on your resume.

Comment: Home automation is something solving real needs with short scripts interfacing with actual APIs that you can do without an employer.

Answer (score 3):

> I've written scripts, but they're max like 100 lines.  So, I don't think it's worth showing.

You should still briefly describe those scripts in your resume. That will help a lot as the companies will know that you actually have practical experiences on your desired field (as a linux/windows system administrator). You can tailor your resume to talk more about these scripts than the node.js.

Furthermore, you can also include the node.js projects in your resume as it shows that you are resourceful, have experiences on many areas, and can handle different aspects of the jobs.

---

In addition, you can describe your help desk work experiences such as:

Helping the internal or external customers with their technical issues:

1. Solve 30 help tickets per week.
2. Install and upgrade softwares/hardware on 5 computers per day.
3. Fix virus on 5 computers per day.
4. Fix 3 software issues and 2 hardware issues per day.

Even though these tasks may not be directly related to the computer administrator jobs, they show your work history, your technical skills, and your interactions with the internal/external customers. It will make your resume look good.

Answer (score 0):

Writing Scripts and referencing them is good... But what I would want to know is the wider context around it:

- What you did to identify a recurring issue
- How you decided to resolve it
- How you tested and implemented your resolution
- Anything you would have done differently

As a (former) Sysadmin - I want to know how you are thinking about *the bigger picture* - Writing a 100 line script is great, but if you have to spend 10 minutes customizing it to run it on a different server, then it's less than ideal. Whereas if you've spent the time to genericize it so that it can be run remotely on multiple systems without issue - that is what I want to hear about.

That's the difference between a helpdesk engineer and a sysadmin - the Helpdesk engineer (and no shade is intended here) is just responsible for resolving the current ticket within the agreed timeframe, whereas the sysadmin has a much wider responsibility with a broader frame of reference.